# How do I get a value in an array into a void onclicklistener?

Tags: java, android, arrays, intellij-idea

I am working on a project and below my code basically takes an array of objects and sets the Id to each object, However, when I click on my objects I would like to get that Id. I tried a local variable and I could only get the Id of the last object, how do I do this? I would like to get the value of String Answerid = currentQuestions.getString("id"); into my OnDown clicklistener.

```
  mVolleySingleton = VolleySingleton.getInstance();
    mRequestQueue = mVolleySingleton.getRequestQueue();

    JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_ANSWER, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            listblogs = parseJSONResponseQuestion(response);
            mAdapterQuestion.setBloglist(listblogs);
            System.out.println(response);
            System.out.println("it worked!!!");
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            System.out.println(error);

        }
    });
    mRequestQueue.add(request);
}

String globalVar = " ";

private ArrayList<Blogs> parseJSONResponseQuestion(JSONArray response) {
    if (!response.equals("")) {
        ArrayList<Blogs> blogsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject currentQuestions = response.getJSONObject(i);
                String text = currentQuestions.getString("text");
                String questionId = currentQuestions.getString("questionId");
                String votes = currentQuestions.getString("votes");
                String Answerid = currentQuestions.getString("id");
                System.out.println(response.length() + "length");

                data.append(text + Answerid + "\n");

                System.out.println(data);
                Blogs blogs = new Blogs();
                blogs.setMtext(text);
                blogs.setVotes(votes);
                blogs.setId(Answerid);
                System.out.print(Answerid);
                listblogs.add(blogs);
            }
            System.out.println(data.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return listblogs;
}

public void OnDown(View view) {

    System.out.println("VOTED Down");
    final RequestQueue mrequestQueue = VolleySingleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue();
    final String PUT_VOTE_UP = "someURL";

    StringRequest PostVoteUp = new StringRequest(Request.Method.PUT, PUT_VOTE_UP, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            System.out.println(response + "reponse");

        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("************Answer" + error + "error");
        }
    });
    mrequestQueue.add(PostVoteUp);
    System.out.println("VOTED DOWN");

}
```

}

Comment: Can I ask, what are the views that are being clicked on? Where is `listblogs` being used after you return it? If the views that are being clicked on have IDs, then there's a solution, or if you're using a `ListView` or `RecyclerView` or something similar, we can figure something out as well.

Comment: Is this some Adapter? You'll need to post your getView() method

Answer (score 0):

Your click listener `OnDown(View view)` gets a view that was clicked. That's the only way you can identify what was clicked.

You should use View.getTag() to get the id:

```
Object obj = view.getTag();
```

The question is where can you add this code to set it:

```
View view = ...; // new View()?
view.setTag(object);
```